# How to add a border to an element that's using clip-path?

Tags: css, clip-path

I have an image that's been clipped using the CSS clip-path property, details below -

[image]

```
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, calc(20% - 100px) 100%, 100% calc(100% - 100px), 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
```

Is it possible to add a bottom border to it to follow the line of the clip path?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://css-tricks.com/using-box-shadows-and-clip-path-together/